# Alloy - Count atoms used by other atoms

Tags: predicate, signature, alloy, predicates

I'm trying to notice a change in atom relations to other atoms. Using the below signatures :

```
    sig Word, Definition{}

    sig Dictionary {
        def: Word -> lone Definition
    }
```

I then use a predicate to show what happens when you add a new relation to a `Dictionary` by having another `Dictionary`which is the same but with one more relation.

```
    pred addRelation [d,d':Dictionary,w:Word,f:Definition] { 
        d'.word = d.word + w -> f 
    }
```

To see if the number of `Word` atoms used by the first Dictionary increase I can show only the instances where this occurs using:

```
    #d'.def.Definition > #d.def.Definition
```

However, is there a way to see if the number of `Definition` atoms used by the second `Dictionary` atom has increased? I've been using trial and error in the Alloy Evaluator to try and find a value for this but have come up short.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
sig Word, Definition{}

sig Dictionary {
    def: Word -> lone Definition
}

pred addRelation [d,d':Dictionary,w:Word,f:Definition] { 
    d'.def = d.def + w -> f 
    #d'.def[Word] > #d.def[Word]
}
run addRelation
```